# Java inheritance multiple some questions

Tags: java

I have some doubts about java inheritance, I'd like to know if I understood correctly.

Just want to make sure I understood it correctly, will be glad if someone could help out.

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/6gh0qp.gif]

Comment: When you have `class A extends C`, we say `A extends C`. Your arrows are pointing wrong direction and you seem to have multiple inheritance.

Comment: `C extends A,B` is multiple inheritance. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance

Comment: My arrows are pointing to the wrong directions because that how it should be by the computer science books.

Comment: This question should have actually been a comment on your previous question, that's why you're getting the downvotes. [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for more info.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, example 2 and 3 are not correct. It clearly states, that A extends B and C, besides you have it *drawn*.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more clear.

**Not allowed**

```
class A{
}

class B{
}

// This is NOT allowed
class C extends A,B{ 
}
```

**allowed**

```
class A{
}

class B extends A{
}

class C extends A{
}
```

**allowed**

```
class A{
}

class B extends A{
}

class C extends B{
}
```

Comment: To be even more _explicitly_ clear: the first example in this answer (the "Not allowed" one) is multiple inheritance (hence "Not allowed"). The second one is single (_not_ multiple) inheritance — the fact that multiple classes extend the same class is not "multiple inheritance." The third is also single inheritance — it's a subclass of a subclass, but `C` is inheriting from `B`, not (directly) from `A`.